# Daily access control with ModSecurity

Tags: apache2, apache2.2, mod-security

I want to configure ModSecurity to limit the access to certain resources to a certain count each day.

E.g: User "A" is allowed to download any file in a specific directory, but the total downloads must not exceed 5.

I keep track of the user accesses using the `user` collection:

```
# initialize collection for the user
SecAction "phase:2,id:1,initcol:user=%{REQUEST_HEADERS:User},nolog"

# check if the the limit is reached and respond with status 403
SecRule USER:REQUESTS "@gt 5" "phase:2,id:3,deny,status:403"

# increment the request count variable upon success
SecAction phase:4,id:4,setvar:user.requests=+1
```

Now I want to clear the `requests` field in the `user` collection every day, so that the user has the full download slots for the next day.

I know of the [`expirevar`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#expirevar) action, but that only allows to specify the number of seconds until the variable shall be cleared, but not the exact time that shall happen.

Is there a possibility to expire the variable that way?

Another option would be a cron-job that runs every day at the same time and clears the stored variables for all users. Unfortunately there is no documentation of where the values are stored and how I can modify them.

Is there a way I can access the stored collection for the users to allow the clearing of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the TIME_HOUR variable of ModSecurity to run a rule at a specific hour of the day. This could help you unset that variable everyday.

Example: SecRule TIME_HOUR "@eq 23" "phase:1,id:'9000080007',setvar:!user.requests"

Please refer to the ModSec RefMan @ https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#TIME_HOUR

Let me know how it works.